# Multiple images from JSON array to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview

I am using tabman for tab like layout. In my case there are 4 tabs which contain 2 to 3 images each. I am showing that images in `UICollectionView`.

My JSON:

```
"PhotoList": [
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 1,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 1,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 2,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\3.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 2,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\4.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 3,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 4,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\6.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "DaySeq": 5,
        "ImgPath": "Images\\7.jpg"
    }
]
```

I want in tab one there is a `UICollectionView` and I want to display only that images which having 'DaySeq' 1. As like this in other tab I want images with 'DaySeq' 2.

What I am trying in code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request("http://bestapp.in/api/Package/GetItineraryByPackageID/2").responseJSON(completionHandler: { (responseData) in

        if ((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

            let swiftyJSONVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let resData = swiftyJSONVar["DayDescrList"].arrayObject,
            let resImg = swiftyJSONVar["PhotoList"].arrayObject
            {

            self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            self.arrImg = resImg as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            self.dataSource = self
            self.bar.location = .top
            }
        }
    })
}
func viewControllers(forPageboyViewController pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController) -> [UIViewController]? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main)

    var viewControllers = [UIViewController] ()
    var tabBarItems : [TabmanBar.Item] = []

    for j in 0 ..< self.arrImg.count {
        for var k in 0 ..< j {
        k += 1
        if k == self.arrImg[j]["DaySeq"] as! Int {
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "childvc") as! childvc
            vc.imgURL = self.arrImg[j]["ImgPath"] as! String
            print(self.arrImg[j]["ImgPath"] as! String)
            self.array.append(self.arrImg[j]["ImgPath"] as! String)
        }

       print(array)
    }

    }
    print(array)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "childvc") as! childvc
    vc.array = array
    self.bar.items = tabBarItems
    return viewControllers

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse through "SwiftyJSON".

1. Create a model example:

   ```
   class ImagesModel {
     var id: Int?
     var path: String?
     var daySeq: Int?

     func parseWith(json: JSON){
        self.id = json["ID"].intValue
        self.path = json["ImgPath"].intValue
        self.daySeq = json["DaySeq"].intValue
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create array of ImagesModel in your class:

   ```
   var imagesModelArray = [ImagesModel]()
   ```
3. Just parse your array into this model example:

   ```
   let photosListArray = json["PhotoList"].arrayValue
   for objects in photosListArray{
      let model = ImagesModel()
      model.parseWith(json: objects)
      self.imagesModelArray.append(model)
   }
   ```
4. After that in collection View numberOfItems method you need to just sort data according to there tab.

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tab == 0{
            return self.imagesModelArray.filter({$0.daySeq == 0})
        }else if tab == 1{
            return self.imagesModelArray.filter({$0.daySeq == 1})
        }
        ///MORE CONDITIONS
        //At the End
        return 0
   }
   ```

After that make these type of filtered Arrays in cellForItem and get image from these filtered array.

Enjoy Swift.

Maybe it's Helpful. If any query please comment

Comment: Thanks For your answer